# Second Torus spawn bigger than first?

Tags: modeling, mesh

When I create a *Torus* mesh and sometime or immediately after add a second mesh, the second one will always be thicker.

[image]

Other meshes won't act like this when creating a second one. It only happens with the torus mesh. Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance !